# How to get the month from a string in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have to get the month  from a column which stores string in format -

```
Column
----------
`Feb2007'     
'Sep2008'
```

So if the value was `'Feb2007'` then I need to get back `2` or else if the value was `'Sep2009'` then I should get back `9`.

Is there inbuilt function in SQL Server 2008 to achieve something like this?

Comment: The values are stored in a comma separated list?

Comment: No, it just stored as one entry. I mean one row has value Feb2007 and then second row has value Sep2008

Comment: I hope you're not storing the `'` quotes in the column too! varchar dates are bad enough!

Comment: I hope there are no `Sept2008` strings in there :)

Comment: Ya..I am not...I am working with legacy database which has varchar dates and asking to change anything is blashphemy!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
select datepart(mm, cast('feb2008' as datetime))
```

Comment: I guess it really depends on regional settings. I bet it may be possible for sql server to not recognize this string as date.

Comment: I always shiver when someone stores a date/time as VARCHAR/etc rather than the native DATE/TIME data type...

Comment: @OMG Ponies What about xml import with no xsd attached? Or Excel data connected to your sql server? Or whatever. Those issues are par for the course.

Answer (score 3):

also this:

SELECT MONTH(CAST(date_col AS datetime))

Comment: Or just `select month('sep2008')`

Answer (score 1):

If nothing else, you can create a table with your month names and numeric values.

If the server function always recognizes your month names correctly, you're good, but if any of that data was entered manually, there could be misspellings or other inconsistencies, and a table would allow you to support them.

Answer (score 0):

I heartily agree with Beth here - but with justifications as to why it should be done as opposed to as a last resort:

Data should be stored in its native format. You should no more store it as a string than you should an 8-bit integer. It makes just as much/little sense. SQL is a very intelligent beast, but if you screw up your fundamental data types most of its useful functionality and heuristics goes out of the window - even basic stuff like **indexing** and **sorting**. Not to mention your data becomes SQL Server explicit (ie. relies on certain SQL behaviour) as opposed to generic, reducing portability.

To put it in more formal terms: you're forcing it to become information at the data layer. This is antithesis to all known rules of data handling.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT month(column);
```

This should work, it's been a while since I've used SQL Server, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
    datepart(month,_datetime)
```

where _datetime is the column. you can also use

```
    datepart(month,getdate())
```

to get the current month

Answer (score 0):

Might need to revisit your database design, if at all possible.  Much more efficient to convert it to datetime before storing in the table.  For example, finding a range of dates will take much longer than it needs to because you'd have to cast each distinct value before finding the dates in your range.